# Jersey/JAX-RS put, delete idempotency - provided or to be done by the programmer

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http, jersey

According to REST, put, delete etc are idempotent, i.e. the operation done on a resource repeatedly results in same response. Is this done automatically somehow (caching on browser etc), or is it to be done/ ensured by programmer (in the method)?
Is this idempotency just symbolic?

For example, in my method to handle the delete request -

```
@DELETE
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public Response deleteEmployee() {
        String response = DAOaccess.deleteEmployee(name);
        return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

I could do anything inside this method. So, do I have to ensure idempotency here, by writing such code (checking for `id` etc)?

When somebody asks me the difference between put and post, are they asking from HTTP perspective, and not from JAX-RS (since maybe there is no functional difference there in JAX-RS)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the developer is responsible for ensuring idempotency here. PUT and DELETE *should* be idempotent according to the standard, but there is plenty of room for interpretation as to what that means. JAX-RS does relatively little to ensure that the developer is following REST best-practices, and will route every request to the appropriate endpoint, absent a filter that short-circuits the request.

Does the second delete call return a 204 or a 404? Either response leaves the system in the same state given repeated calls to the same method; one signals the client that there was no resource for it to delete, and the other signals the client that there definitely is no such resource at this time.

The only *wrong* implementation (according to the REST standard) would be for the system to *toggle* the deleted status of the resource on repeated calls - this would leave the client unsure as to what effect its next call would have on the system.